# Entering Kenya as dual citizen with UK passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, africa, kenya

The question isn't regarding the legality of it but rather the practical benefits. I did read on another forum that although It costs more to enter Kenya with a UK passport, if I am caught in trouble (e.g political violence, robbery), the British consulate has no power to help me if I enter with my Kenyan one.

Is this true?

Comment: In general, a country can deny consular assistance to its own nationals regardless of the passport they used.  Some countries have agreements to the contrary, however.  I don't know whether such an agreement exists between the UK and Kenya, or perhaps more generally in the commonwealth, but that might help you find what you're looking for on the wider internet if nobody here can answer.

Answer (score 1):

The limits on consular assistance are because you are a dual national, so the UK cannot help if you have obligations as a Kenyan (eg military service).
Robbery would be a local police matter unless your UK passport is stolen.
Political violence: be as careful as if you were not a UK citizen. Don't assume the consulate has the resources to help you even if they have the right to help.